# Can't register smartcard in reader with LockHub

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

I have a capsule hostel with smart locks in every capsule. With the capsules, i got a smart cards. One of them - white (I think it is master card) I'm using to program locks in the capsules for the usual card (black). 
[image: Cards]
But I have a problem - every usual card can fits to every lock, I think they have an identical PIN inside. So I want to re-write them to be unique.

I have an USB Smart Card Reader (MODEL t307-C) and LockHub(Cabinet Lock)v8 software with CH341SER Driver. LockHub wants to be registered with Authorization Card (It must be shipped with your locks). I try to register it with my white card, but it says 'Error reading card'. Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How sure are you, that reader and cards are compatible (use same standard, frequency range, ...)? The same PIN does not need to be a problem, surely the lock compares specific dates like room number (and I assume an expiry date). WIthout substantial documentation (hardware vendor?) I consider the chances of progress rather slim.

Comment: Thank you. I see that reader can see this cards in other operations (but only says that LockHub is unregistered). I'll try with documentation soon, when I find it. Can you reccomend some other software for my Broad Road hotel card reader  RW-125K type LOCKHUB t307-C?

Comment: I assume, that 125K means 125 kHz carrier frequency, so [this reader](https://www.tomtop.com/p-h20946.html) might fit, but I have no experience with it (I could not find anything named *t307-C*) and also no software is mentioned.